# Handling a url which fails to open, error handling using urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I would like some help on how to handle an url which fails to open, currently the whole program gets interrupted when it fails to open the url ( tree = ET.parse(opener.open(input_url)) )...

If the opening of an url fails on my first function call (motgift) I would like it to wait 10 seconds and then try to open the url again, if it once again fails I would like my script to continue with next function call (observer).

```
def spider_xml(input_url, extract_function, input_xpath, pipeline, object_table, object_model):

        opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
        tree = ET.parse(opener.open(input_url))
        print(object_table)

        for element in tree.xpath(input_xpath):

            pipeline.process_item(extract_function(element), object_model)


motgift = spider_xml(motgift_url, extract_xml_item, motgift_xpath, motgift_pipeline, motgift_table, motgift_model)
observer = spider_xml(observer_url, extract_xml_item, observer_xpath, observer_pipeline, observer_table, observer_model)
```

Would be very happy and appreciate an example on how to make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a Try Except block work?

```
error = 0
while error < 2:
  try:
    motgift = spider_xml(motgift_url, extract_xml_item, motgift_xpath,   motgift_pipeline, motgift_table, motgift_model
    break
  except:
    error += 1
    sleep(10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ovet, something like this I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    resp = opener.open(input_url)
except Exception:
    time.sleep(10)
    try:
        resp = opener.open(input_url)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Are you looking for this?

Comment: yes something like it, however i don't like the repeating of resp = opener.open(input_url)